# The line-height css property does not work in a JEditorPane. Can anyone help?

Tags: java, html, css

When I place the following html in a JEditorPane, the line-height attr is not obeyed (the font and color ones are though). Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I checked the html in firefox and it's fine.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      p {
        color:#222222;  
        line-height: 200%;
        font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
     <p>flkdjflssd flsdjf sldfkjsdlf jlsdjfs lfjsldjf sldjfdl fslf sljfs dlfsj fjsd lfsd lfjsdlfj sldfjls df dlfsldf sldfjs ldjflsdjf sldfj sldfjsldfjsldjfsldjfsldjfsldjf sdlfsdlfs dlfs dflsjd flsdjf slfj sdlfjsldfj sdljf sldfjsd lfjsldf sldf sdfs lfjsdfsfkj sdfs dfjdf sldfjsldf sldfsldf sfjsldf sdf
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can give the [xhtmlrenderer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//) a try. I think it should have better support for CSS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. Funnily enough I just stumbled upon it myself and it is just what I need. I discovered that javax.swing.text.html.CSS simply does not support the line-height property.